# Power query: Passing a table within a cell to a custom function

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm pretty new to custom functions in Power Query.
I've created this one. Its purpose is to add a custom column whose content AND name are based on the parameters it gets. I've saved it as **fnCompactedExamples**:

```
let

    CompactedExamples = (BaseTable as table, ExamplesTable as table, ExampleNumber as text) =>

        let
            Source = BaseTable,
            #"Add example column" = Table.AddColumn( Source, "sb" & ExampleNumber, each Table.Column( ExamplesTable, Campaign & "_b" & ExampleNumber & "_example")),
            #"Extracted values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Add example column", { "sb" & ExampleNumber, each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(List.Transform(_, Text.From)), "#(lf)"), type text} )
        in
            #"Extracted values"

in
     CompactedExamples
```

This function gets called in the following query:

```
let
    Source = #"raw entities table",
    #"Group by cny ID and Cny" = Table.Group(Source, {"Company ID", "Company"}, {{"Data", each _, type table}}),
    #"create sb1 column" = fnCompactedExamples(#"Group by cny ID and Cny", [Data], "1")
in
    #"create sb1 column"
```

Here is what the table looks like on the "Group by cny ID and Cny" stage

[image: Table]

But on the "create sb1 column" stage, I get an error: "Expression.Error: There is an unknown identifier. Did you use the [field] shorthand for a _[field] outside of an 'each' expression?"

I feel close to the end, and that my error is some tiny detail. I scoured the web for hints on my case, but couldn't find any. Can anybody tell me what it that detail?

*Edit, per @Olly's request:*

The second argument ExamplesTable , is indeed a table that bears columns I want to kinda concatenate without any duplicate:
[image: input table]

My purpose is to build a table like this, but right now I use a very repetitive series of instructions :
[image: output table]

Comment: Your query calls your function once, and passes a list of tables to the second argument - this is what's causing the error, as the function expects one table for the second argument. It's not clear how to fix this, as your actual requirement isn't clear... [Edit] your question to show an example of your input and your expected output.

Comment: OK, I added precisions; hope they're clear for you. My edit is awaiting moderation it seems.

Comment: I wish you'd post a sample of your actual SOURCE data, rather than a half way point - there's almost certainly a much simpler way of achieving your required output.

Comment: @Olly, [here it is](https://i.imgur.com/UDJaKfj.png)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly simpler solution, which unpivots your 'example' columns, renames them appropriately, then pivots again, combining distinct values in the output:

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Company ID", "Company"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Attributes" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {{"Attribute", each "s" & Text.BetweenDelimiters(_, "_", "_"), type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Renamed Attributes", List.Distinct(#"Renamed Attributes"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(_),", "))
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

You can then tweak this to suit - for example, this removes blank values, sorts each list, and separates values with a linefeed:

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Company ID", "Company"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Empty Values" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each [Value] <> null and [Value] <> ""),
    #"Renamed Attributes" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Empty Values", {{"Attribute", each "s" & Text.BetweenDelimiters(_, "_", "_"), type text}}),
    #"Sorted Attributes" = Table.Sort(#"Renamed Attributes",{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Attributes", List.Distinct(#"Sorted Attributes"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", each Text.Combine(List.Sort(List.Distinct(_)),"#(lf)"))
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```